# Bundle fails to open MSI file

Tags: installation, wix, burn

I'm creating a bundle for my installer, but I keep getting the following error message:

> "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the
>   application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer
>   package."

My installer works fine when I start it manually. Is there anything wrong with my bundle? I'm using WiX 3.7. Also, does the upgrade code in the bundle and the installer have to be the same?

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="$(var.Version)" 
            Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)"
            UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)"
            Copyright="Copyright© 2013"
            Condition="((VersionNT >= v5.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 3)) OR
              ((VersionNT >= v5.2) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 2)) OR (VersionNT >= v6.0)"> 

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Id="Setup" Compressed="yes" SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)"
                        Vital="yes">
                <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Though not the case here, one gets the exact same symptom if the "setup.exe" file is specified instead of the ".msi" file (for `SourceFile=`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of a `Bundle` element is an executable. You cannot pass that executable to the Windows Installer. Simply double click it and it should run. If it does not, look in the `%TEMP%` folder and you should see a log file with the name of your `Bundle` or a `Setup_*.log` file. That log file should have more details about why the executable failed to start.

Second, the `UpgradeCode` of a `Bundle` is completely independent of the `UpgradeCode` of your .msi file.

Comment: Ah, now I realise what the problem is. I'm trying to encapsulate the .msi in a bundler, but I specified the output as a .msi file. When I changed it to an .exe file it worked! Thanks! :)